# ObservableCollection and ProgressBar don't work together

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml

I want to import data from a file to `ObservableCollection` through `Add` method. And I also want the property IsIndeterminate of ProgressBar should be `true` during loading file.

Therefore I will have two threads:

1. Show ProgressBar.
2. Load the data from a file to `ObservableCollection`.

But I have two problems.

1. `ObservableCollection` doesn't work in the thread where it wasn't created.

OR

2. If I use `Dispatcher` in the second thread it blocks the first thread and ProgressBar not works.

**Questions:**

1. Can I hear your ideas?  How would you solve this problem?
2. How can I make a friend them? :)

**C#:**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Collection { get; set; }
public bool ProgressIsIndeterminate { get; set; }
CommandImportBaseFile = new Command(async (o) => { await DoImportFileAsync(); });

private async Task DoImportBaseFileAsync()
{
    OpenFileDialog serviceDialogs = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (serviceDialogs.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string message = null;
        ProgressIsIndeterminate = true;
        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(serviceDialogs.FileName)) throw new Exception("File is not found - " + serviceDialogs.FileName + ".");
                MyClass data = new MyClass();
                BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(serviceDialogs.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    data = (MyClass)binFormat.Deserialize(fStream);
                }
                foreach (var d in data)
                {
                    Collection.Add(d);
                }
            });
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.Message;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            message = "Completed";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
        ProgressIsIndeterminate = false;
    }
}
```

OR I use `Dispatcher`

```
foreach (var d in data)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        Collection.Add(d);
    });
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ProgressBar
    Width="100"
    Height="12"
    IsIndeterminate="{Binding ProgressIsIndeterminate}"/>
```

**Update:**

**C#:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Name = String.Empty;
        Age = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the `ObservableCollection<T>` MSDN page: "Thread Safety: Any public static members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**" You can't use `ObservableCollection<T>` on multiple threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know that. I ask your opinion, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: Try calling ```App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke``` instead of ```BeginInvoke```.  You either want to add all the data at once or add it one data at a time.  If you use ```BeginInvoke``` then you may potentially have a large queue or items on the dispatcher, which may not be bad but definitely isn't good, it may also be why you're blocking the ```ProgressBar``` for noticeable periods of time.

Comment: @Kirill - don't use `ObservableCollection<T>`? What does the real code for `DoImportFileAsync` look like?

Comment: @Enigmativity There is nothing essentially there, simple `if`, data check, that is all. Other problem, I use `ObservableCollection` in `DataGrid`. If I will change ObservableCollection that it should be similar `ObservableCollection` class. Will `BindingList` help me?

Comment: @Kirill - That's not thread-safe either. What does the real code for `DoImportFileAsync` look like?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Better, but sometimes ProgressBar freeze. Really, I have a lot of data. And each item of data subscribes on three events at moment then app import item.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated the post.

Comment: @Kirill - That doesn't appear to be the actual working code. It doesn't compile and it doesn't use the `serviceDialogs` object to get the file name.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I have updated again. I just have a lot of classes.

Comment: @Kirill - What's `MyClass`? I'm trying to get `DoImportFileAsync` to compile, but without [mcve] it's hard.

Comment: @Kirill - That can't be your real code - `data = (MyClass)binFormat.Deserialize(fStream);` as `data` is `MyClass` and you do `foreach (var d in data)` which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Since .NET 4.5 you can also use: `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_yourCollection, _lock)`. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845(v=vs.110).aspx). This will make your Collection ThreadSafe !

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated the post, please look at. Now I hope I have given you all the classes to compile.

Answer (score 4):

You want to separate long running work from updating UI. Your async code should not be responsible for doing the work *and* updating UI. You should use for example `IProgress<T>` to notify UI about changes.

Here is example:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _progressValue;
        public double ProgressValue {
            get => _progressValue;
            set
            {
                _progressValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private ICommand _onLoadCommand;
        public ICommand OnLoadCommand => _onLoadCommand ?? 
                                         (_onLoadCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => true, p => OnLoad()));

        private async void OnLoad()
        {
            var progress = new Progress<Tuple<string, double>>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += OnWorkProgress;
            await DoWork(progress);
        }

        private void OnWorkProgress(object sender, Tuple<string, double> e)
        {
            Values.Add(e.Item1);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Values));
            ProgressValue = e.Item2 * 100;
        }

        private async Task DoWork(IProgress<Tuple<string, double>> progress)
        {
            const int elementsCount = 500;
            for (int index = 0; index < elementsCount; index++)
            {
                var result = "Value_" + index;
                await Task.Delay(10);
                progress.Report(Tuple.Create(result, (double)index / elementsCount));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null) => 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And View:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" Height="30"></ProgressBar>
    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Separator>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" Height="250"></ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is how it works:

1. `OnLoad` is Window's event handler that gets called when window
   loads. This is a good place to start using async code.
2. We create `Progress<T>` instance that we will use as a way of 
   communicating between UI and ThreadPool thread.
3. We subscribe on UI thread to `ProgressChanged` that is an event that
   is used for our communication
4. We start doing the async work `await DoWork(progress);` and pass
   reference to `progress`.
5. Async code does its job and once it finished a chunk of it, it
   reports to UI thread (or whatever the listeners are) about how much
   work is done using `progress.Report`.
6. The report is then displayed by `OnWorkProgress` on UI thread.

EDIT:
If you want to run this you will need `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF` nuget package.

EDIT2:

This is how you would do this for CPU bound work:

```
private async void OnLoad()
{
    var progress = new Progress<Tuple<string, double>>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += OnWorkProgress;
    await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));
}

private void OnWorkProgress(object sender, Tuple<string, double> e)
{
    Values.Add(e.Item1);
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Values));
    ProgressValue = e.Item2 * 100;
}

private void DoWork(IProgress<Tuple<string, double>> progress)
{
    const int elementsCount = 500;
    for (int index = 0; index < elementsCount; index++)
    {
        var result = "Value_" + index;
        Thread.Sleep(10); // don't do this. Do CPU intensive work here...
        progress.Report(Tuple.Create(result, (double)index / elementsCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't separation long-running work from updating UI. My problem is adding item ObservableCollection in other thread or other class similar to ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Kirill The point is you should not add items to `ObservableCollection` from another thread. You should do long running work in one thread and add the result 
 to a collection in UI thread.

Comment: This is the main question of how can I do it? How can I load data, update UI and show ProgressBar during all it?

Comment: In your example where can i update UI with `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @Kirill `OnWorkProgress` updates UI with data from `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Hm... Do you propose load data at `DoWork` and throw loaded data at `OnWorkProgress` and add data to ObservableCollection there? Do I right understand?

Comment: @Kirill Yes. I presented runnable example. You can pretty much copy/paste it and see for yourself how it works. Good thing about this approach is that you separate responsibilities. `OnWork` is responsible for doing long running work and it should not be interested in anything else. `OnWorkProgress` is only responsible for UI stuff and doesn't care from where it gets the data.

Comment: Sorry, but it is magic. :) It is all in one thread. I can't see where you create a new thread or it doesn't need. Do you sure that ProgressBar will not freeze?

Comment: @Kirill I'm not creating a new thread. I'm using thread from a ThreadPool. When you use `Task.Run`, you schedule work on a ThreadPool thread. I use `await Task.Delay(10)` just to simulate long running work, but because you do CPU bound work you want to use `await Task.Run(() => {})`. When you call `await Task.Run()`, a task is assigned to one of already created threads and the task is computed on the first free thread. If you want to use tasks, then you should read about ThreadPool.

Comment: Can you give me your `RelayCommand`. I want to compile your code. I have some small problems.

Comment: @Kirill This is the standard implementation that you can find everywhere. Here is [example implementation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/)

Comment: I have seemed to understand why it doesn't compile. I have changed `RelayCommand(_ => true, p => OnLoad())` to `RelayCommand(p => OnLoad(), _ => true)`. Probably, you wanted to do so.

Comment: Also moment, this code doesn't work without `Thread.Sleep(10)`. More precisely it works but it freezes threads. I set up `elementsCount` to 500000, and comment `Thread.Sleep(10)`. Is it possible to decide this problem or it's not possible to decide?

Comment: @Kirill It freezes because you update UI 500000 times in a very short period of time. Users probably don't need to see progress bar changing by 0.00001%. You should only report every couple of thousands of iterations, e.g. `if(index % 5000 == 0) { progress.Report(...); }`. This means you probably would want to store 5000 objects in a list and then report that list, not every single element.

Comment: @Kirill Also, you probably don't want to store hundreads of thousands of items in `ObservableCollection`. Firstly, who would want to filter a list with > 100000 items. Secondly, it is very expensive to add items to ObservableCollection so you would have to add them to temporary list and then add it in bulk, e.g. `new ObservableCollection<string>(tempList)`;

Comment: Any case, it freezes. It looks like the code needs more time for update UI than data load. Probably, the code can not get in time update UI and it is immediately getting a new data for update UI while it doesn't still complete work with first data. And I have gotten a frozen ProgressBar. It seems that only one method solve this problem - `Thread.Sleep(1);`

Comment: I got to know that the 5000 items - the delay is 3000 ms, maybe a little less. And if I will use tempList and load in its part of the data and then add data to collection my delay increasing double. Because I will add items in two collections: data to tempList (part of all), tempList to MyWorkCollection (full collection). With delay is correctly show ProgressBar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176334/discussion-between-fcin-and-kirill).

Answer (score -2):

Use background thread and use the method runcompleted and progress to update the progress bar. ObservableCollection needs begin invoke instead of invoke to update the changes. Hope that will block UI or your thread

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. It's also wrong on many counts. No collection needs `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`, that's for *UI* elements. Even these aren't needed if you use MVVM, set a progress property and raise the PropertyChanged event. There's no `runcompleted` method.